# Comprehensible lower bound for $1 - \sum_{n=0}^{d-1} \frac{\lambda^{nd}}{1+(n+1)(d-1)}$ with $\lambda \in (0,1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I have the following expression for $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $d \in \{2,3,\dots\}$:
$$A(\lambda,d) := 1 - \sum_{n=0}^{d-1} \frac{\lambda^{nd}}{1+(n+1)(d-1)},$$
clearly we always have $A(\lambda,d) > 0$, and as $\lambda \rightarrow 1$, we have $A(\lambda,d) \rightarrow 0$ and as $\lambda \rightarrow 0$, we have $A(\lambda,d) \rightarrow 1 - \frac{1}{d}$. However, I wonder what happens in between.

Comment: The assertion that $A(λ, d) \to 0 \ (λ \to 0)$ seems false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}{{\lambda^{nd}}\over{1+(n+1)(d-1)}}=\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}{{\lambda^{nd}}\over{nd+d-n}}$ therefore:
$${1\over{\lambda^d}}{\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}{{\lambda^{(n+1)d}}\over{(n+1)d}}}\le g(x)\le {1\over d}+{\sum_{n=1}^{d-1}{{\lambda^{nd}}\over{nd}}}$$
Now define $f_1(\lambda;d)={\sum_{n=1}^{d}{{\lambda^{nd}}\over{nd}}}$ and $f_2(\lambda;d)={1\over d}+{\sum_{n=1}^{d-1}{{\lambda^{nd}}\over{nd}}}$ by differentiating we get:
$${{df_1(\lambda;d)}\over{d(\lambda)^d}}={1\over {d}}\sum_{n=1}^{d}{(\lambda^d)^{n-1}}={1\over d}{{{1-\lambda^{d^2}}}\over{1-\lambda^d}}$$
$${{df_2(\lambda;d)}\over{d(\lambda)^d}}={1\over d}{{{1-\lambda^{d(d-1)}}}\over{1-\lambda^d}}$$
Then we have:
$$f_1(\lambda;d)={1\over {d}}\int_{0}^{\lambda^d}{{1-u^d}\over{1-u}}du$$
$$f_2(\lambda;d)={1\over d}+{1\over d}\int_{0}^{\lambda^d}{{1-u^{d-1}}\over{1-u}}du$$
The functions $f_1(x;d)$ and $f_2(x;d)$ have no closed forms then they can be bounded by

$$f_1(x;d)>{{\lambda^{d^2}}\over{d^2}}$$
and 
$$f_2(x;d)<{1\over d}\ln {{e}\over{1-\lambda^d}}$$

so we can write

$$1-{1\over d}\ln {{e}\over{1-\lambda^d}}<A(x,d)<1-{{\lambda^{d^2}}\over{d^2}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer! I only wonder: how do you bound the integral $\int_0^{\lambda^d} \frac{1-u^{d-1}}{1-u} du$?

Comment: That's very kind of you!....in fact since $0<\lambda<1$ so is $0<u^{d-1}<\lambda^{d-1}<1$ and we can write $\frac{u^{d-2}-u^{d-1}}{1-u}\le\frac{1-u^{d-1}}{1-u}$ and you can go forward

Comment: Hey: I've been able to get a tighter upper bound for $f_2(x;d)$, by using the hypergeometric function to express the integral you wrote, it can be shown that it is bounded above by $\frac{1}{d} - \frac{1}{d^2}\sum_{n=1}^{d-1} \frac{\lambda^{dn}}{n}$. Really should always keep in mind the method of bounding sums by integrals!

Comment: Yeap! That's right!